# Xamarin Android App Crashes On Boot

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, boot

I Use Xamarin Android for developing And I get App Crashes error After phone or simulator startup.
other similar posts on web didn't help me.

This is my android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <service android:name=".sobhanService" android:exported="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:label="donya">
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:name=".StartReceiver" android:label="StartReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My StartReceiver class:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled=true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted, Intent.ActionScreenOn })]
    public class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Action Boot Completed!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Intent serviceStart = new Intent(context, typeof(SobhanService));
            serviceStart.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartService(serviceStart);
        }
    }
```

And my SobhanService:

```
 [Service(Label = "SobhanService")]
    [IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.yourname.SobhanService" })]
    public class SobhanService : IntentService
    {
        IBinder binder;
        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            Schedule_GPS();
            Schedule_Notification();
        }
        private void Schedule_GPS()
        {
            try
            {
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Send_Username));
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                long interval = 30000;
                long triggerTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + interval;
                am.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, interval, pi);
                //

            }
            catch { }

        }
        private void Schedule_Notification()
        {
            try
            {
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, typeof(Notification));
                PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                long interval1 = 30000;
                long triggerTime1 = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + interval1;
                am.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime1, interval1, pi1);
            }
            catch { }
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                binder = new SobhanServiceBinder(this);
                return binder;
            }
            catch { return binder; }
        }


        public class SobhanServiceBinder : Binder
        {
            readonly SobhanService service;

            public SobhanServiceBinder(SobhanService service)
            {
                this.service = service;
            }

            public SobhanService GetSobhanService()
            {
                return service;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have installed aLogCat app for logging Android events But it doesn't work properly in simulator.
Thank you So much

Comment: adb logcat cmdline :  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/#Accessing_from_the_Command_Line

Comment: I think there is an error in my code . i don't know where

Comment: Hi, Ahmad, could you please post your error?

Comment: Hi Joe , I don't know How to debug in Released application because i reset phone for check application on boot.